# Path to anaconda folder with graphical installer

Tags: python, macos, installation, anaconda

I have installed anaconda using the graphical installer from [anaconda website](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#macos) on a OS X. 
But I can't find the path to folder anaconda3 on the computer so that I point my python to it. I still have the native Python2 now.

Comment: _so that I point my python to it._ I’m not sure what you mean, can you elaborate? Are you not using conda environments?

Answer (score 1):

Just type *whereis Anaconda* in the terminal. This will tell you the path where it is installed.
You can do same for python too.

Answer (score 0):

just type 
*"Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3)"*  on search and follow the path